# Possible to install "members" command on centos7?

Tags: centos-7

Attempting to install the [`members`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-members-command-examples-usage-syntax/) command to [list group members](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-all-members-of-a-group/), but seeing error where the command does not exist on the system and can't be installed from anywhere (despite the implication in the linked-to article):

```bsh
[airflow@airflowetl dlnfs]$ members
bash: members: command not found


[airflow@airflowetl dlnfs]$ yum info members
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.grid.uchicago.edu
 * epel: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * extras: mirror.oss.ou.edu
 * updates: mirror.siena.edu
maprecosystem                                                                   45/45
maprtech                                                                        23/23
Error: No matching Packages to list


[airflow@airflowetl dlnfs]$ yum search members
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.grid.uchicago.edu
 * epel: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * extras: mirror.oss.ou.edu
 * updates: mirror.siena.edu
================================ N/S matched: members ================================
python-ordered-set.noarch : A Custom MutableSet that remembers its order
voms.x86_64 : Virtual Organization Membership Service
voms-api-java.noarch : Virtual Organization Membership Service Java API
voms-api-java-javadoc.noarch : Virtual Organization Membership Service Java API
                             : Documentation
voms-clients-cpp.x86_64 : Virtual Organization Membership Service Clients
voms-clients-java.noarch : Virtual Organization Membership Service Java clients
voms-devel.x86_64 : Virtual Organization Membership Service Development Files
voms-doc.noarch : Virtual Organization Membership Service Documentation
voms-server.x86_64 : Virtual Organization Membership Service Server

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Am aware of the `getent groups <group name>` command, but was just curious about whether the members command is actually available on centos7 and if so how to get it (again, the article implied that the command could be `yum install`ed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `members` tool was once written by a Debian developer and it seems that it only exists in the form of the [Debian package itself](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/members) – there is no separate "upstream" as such, just a single C file stored directly within the Debian packaging.

This doesn't exactly prevent other distributions from packaging it, but really it's most likely that nobody found it sufficiently useful to be worth the hassle. It ought to have been contributed to the 'shadow' package to be alongside `groups` and similar tools.

The simplest way for you to install it would be to [download the C++ source code](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/members) (the single .cc file) and compile it – which in this case should be as easy as:

```
g++ members.cc -o members
```

or even:

```
make members
```